# Phonegap native date time picker

Tags: cordova, plugins, time, picker

I'm using this to choose times in my app: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker

However, when the native time picker pops up, the time is shown in 24h format instead of 12h, is there a way to make the time appear in 12h format in the picker?

After I choose the time, the input display it in 12h, but when I'm whatch the picker options, they all are in 24h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify line 102 of [DatePickerPlugin.java](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/DatePicker/DatePickerPlugin.java) to be:

```
mMinutes, false);
```

the "false" will tell the time picker to show in 12 hour format.